# Can a Java 8 codebase be compiled and work on a Java 6 VM?

Tags: java, java-8

Will a Java 8 codebase that is compiled with Java 8 work on a Java 6 VM?

Comment: Only if you can compile it with option `-target 1.6`

Comment: In short, only if it's not really a Java 8 code base, you are just using the Java 8 compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but if you don't make use of features of java 7 and java 8 ...

If the codebase is written using features of newer java versions, then ***no*** there's no way to do it!

However, if you want to run them on java 6 you have to set java 6 compliance level(with `-source 1.6 -target 1.6` javac parameters) when you compile source code files, to make them compatible with java 6. If you don't set the compliance as shown above, you will get an [UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html) :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:Unsupported major.minor version XX.X
```

Comment: Don't think so. If copiled with 1.8, you will get the major/minor error message and game over.

Comment: @MightyPork Not if you use `-source 1.6 -target 1.6` and don't use any methods or classes added since 1.6

Comment: Alright, that would work. But then your code is Java 6, not Java 8, so there's really no benefit except not having to download two compilers.

Answer (score 2):

It generally only works the other way around, so running a Java 6 compiled application should run on a JVM of a higher version. The other way around is not possible I'm afraid, unless you don't use any new features and tell `javac` that your source version is 1.6 (i.e. `-source 1.6`) which essentially means you're programming Java 6 :).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what Java 8 features the code is using, you may be able to run [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) on it and use the results in a Java 6 JVM.  Maybe.