# Compile Java codebase into 10 and 8 with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, compilation

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697109/can-a-java-8-codebase-be-compiled-and-work-on-a-java-6-vm) tells me it is indeed possible to compile newer versions into older versions using `--target` and `--source` as well as the newer `--release` commands. Java 10 and Java 8 are very different in set up; 10 using modules whereas 8 does not.

I have attempted this by adding `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` into my `build.gradle`, and I receive a `modules are not supported in -source 8` error. This is of course expected and make sense.

Can I do something similar, or do exactly that, so that I can input a var at my Gradle assemble task to "switch" between Java 8 and Java 10 compiliation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can. I typed out this question and then did a little more research. The only caveat is that you CAN NOT use any higher level Java additions.

Using Gradle, I included a variable in my run statement, similar to this `gradle clean assemble -PjavaVer=8`

Using that variable, I can basically switch off on which code Id like to run. See example below.

```
if(project.hasProperty('javaVer') && javaVer == '8') {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

afterEvaluate {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }
    compileJava {
        if (project.hasProperty(('javaVer')) && javaVer == '8') {
            excludes = ['**/module-info.java']
        } else {
            doFirst {
                options.compilerArgs = [
                        '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                ]
                classpath = files()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will detect if the variable is set to `8`, and if so exlcude the `module-info.java` class, and set the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `1.8`. This worked for me.

Please be aware, you CAN NOT do this if you use Java 10 or 9 specific code, i.e. `var` for Java 10. This is why we had to exclude the `module-info.java` class, since it was introduced in Java 9.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful to you — with the recent *Gradle Modules Plugin* (since version [1.5.0](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin/releases/tag/v1.5.0)), you can actually compile:

- your main code (except `module-info.java`) to Java 8,
- your `module-info.java`, separately, to Java 9.

This is done automatically by [`modularity.mixedJavaRelease`](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javamodularity/moduleplugin/extensions/ModularityExtension.java) method.

Here's a sample of how to apply the plugin to one's main `build.gradle` (assuming it's a multi-project build):

```
plugins {
  // your remaining plugins here

  id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.5.0' apply false
}

subprojects {
  // your remaining subproject configuration here

  apply plugin: 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin'
  modularity.mixedJavaRelease 8 // sets "--release 8" for main code, and "--release 9" for "module-info.java"

  // test.moduleOptions.runOnClasspath = true // optional (if you want your tests to still run on classpath)
}
```